# How to draw only black color from a bitmap image to window (filter colors out except black)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, gdi+, gdi

I am trying to make a Paint program that enables the user change background, while foreground color (that is used in drawing shapes) is always black.
Now, when the user changes background color, the HBRUSH paints the whole window with the chosen color and consequently clears all the shapes that were drawn.
To solve the problem I made 3 steps (note that the problem lies in the third step):

1. saveBeforeBackcolorChange() : a function that saves the window to bitmap before backColor is changed
2. FillRect(hdc, rect, color): paints the whole window with the new color
3. loadAfterBackcolorChanged(): ought to take only black pixels from the bitmap (which represent drawings) and consider any color transparent

Here is my implementation for the third step:

```
void loadAfterBackcolorChanged(HDC hdc){
    ULONG_PTR m_gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    wchar_t* filePathString = new wchar_t[MAX_PATH];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, TEMP_FILE.c_str(), -1, filePathString, 4096);
    Image image(filePathString);
    Gdiplus::ImageAttributes imAtt;
    imAtt.SetColorKey(
        Color(1, 1, 1),
        Color(255, 255, 255),
        ColorAdjustTypeBitmap);
    graphics.DrawImage(
        &image,
        Rect(0, 0, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight()),  // dest rect
        0, 0, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight(),          // source rect
        UnitPixel,
        &imAtt);
}
```

Unfortunately, the result is that it considers only white color transparent. Which means that it works well if the background is white (which is the initial backColor). Consequently the user can change backColor successfully only once!

I will be grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the problem with this sort of approach.  You either need layer info (i.e. store the foreground separately from the background all the time) or a fill algorithm that knows how to selectively fill based on existing pixel color.

Comment: It seems to me you are using the `SetColorkey` function wrongly; those hardcoded values for low color key and high color key do not smell good to me.

Comment: So, how do you think I can achieve my goal?